# Why nodejs is taking CPU?

Tags: linux, performance, node.js

I am new to node. I was writing a sample http server is node http module. After profiling it with jmeter

**Jmeter Test Case:**
Number of threads: 20
Delay after every request : 5ms

Node cpu usage is varying 17%-20% with a simple program.

Node version: v0.10.0
Sample code:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require("url");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;


    var body = "";

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {     
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});            
                res.end('hi vivek');
    });


}).listen(9097, "127.0.0.1");
```

In my sample program I am not doing any cpu task. 
My questions are?

1. Why it is taking that much cpu?
2. How many parallel user request can I support in node?

Comment: “Simple program”... Try to write it in C or assembly and see how simple that is.

Comment: for the real question in your threads: `How many parallel user request can I support in node?` 10k within one process

Comment: @0x90 Source for that?

Comment: @0x90: Does it depend on how much memory or CPU power the computer has? What kind of NIC, kernel and drivers it has? What PCIe slot is used for NIC, after all? Those things can make a big difference IMO.

Comment: @adrianp http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116114/does-node-js-actually-increase-scalability by Josh K

Comment: @VladLazarenko you are right please read the accepted answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/116130

Comment: @0x90 I fail to see how that article **states** that: "Node.js can support 10k [requests] within one process.". And anyway, as Vlad mentioned, this would depend on the underlying OS, hardware, etc.

Comment: @0x90 I do not necessarily disagree on the performance of Node.js, but if we are going to make such claims we should also be able to back them up by repeatable scenarios. There is such a thing called [the scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method).

Comment: @VladLazarenko It will be a hello world https program for a node js developer. That's why I used simple word

Comment: @0x90 My program is simple hello worlds. No complex computation. IO driven. Can you please guide me why node is spiking in this case ?

Comment: @0x90 Another question. I am trying to use node js in one application. Where it receives data of size 100B to 2 KB. It does json parsing. And put it to dynamoDB, mysql and redis. Is node is correct choice for this ?

Comment: @VivekGoel I am not a big fan of Javascript and node. why don't you go for python, django, ruby on rails ? if you need a lot of sessions you can use nginx. I think you can describe your list of demands here on programmers.stackexchange and one will give you pro and cons.

Comment: @0x90 I have posted my question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200220/is-node-js-correct-choice-for-json-parsing-and-io-driven